# set time when image needs to change on mouseover

Tags: php, javascript

I want to set time on mouse-over function in JavaScript.

My code is as follow.

```
<img class="product-image" 
  src='<?php echo $item['0']; ?>' 
  onmouseover="this.src='<?php echo $item2['0']; ?>'" 
  onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $item['0']; ?>'" />.
```

This code is working properly but I want to set time when images replaces on mouse-over event.

Comment: What do you mean by "set time"? Do you mean you want to pre–load images so they are cached and change faster (the first time)?

Comment: No, time travel is not possible.

Comment: @AlvinWong You mean not yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this JavaScript function to change the image only after `t` msec.

```
function delayedImage(obj, src, t)
{
  setTimeout(function() {
    obj.src = src;
  }, t);
}
```

Then use this HTML:

```
<img class="product-image" 
  src='<?php echo $item['0']; ?>' 
  onmouseover="delayedImage(this, '<?php echo $item2['0']; ?>', 2000)" 
  onmouseout="delayedImage(this, '<?php echo $item['0']; ?>', 2000)" />
```

Maybe you don't need it on the `mouseout` though, but that's easy enough to change :)

Comment: Great work Jack thanks alot for all guys who replied.Your answer is rocking.